# Preencher vetor em C

Tags: c, lógica

Tenho um exercício que pede para o professor digitar 5 notas, e exibir as notas digitadas, escrevi o código, mas não está rodando da maneira correta, alguém pode ajudar?

Segue código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
int i = 0;
float nota[5];
float total = 0, media = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
printf("Digite a nota do usuário!\\n");
scanf("%f", &[i]);

}
printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\\n", nota[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%f", &[i])` o que deveria acontecer nesta linha? Porque ele não só não está "rodando da maneira correta", como está dando erro durante a compilação exatamente nesta linha. Ele nem chega a "rodar".

Comment: Essa linha `scanf("%f", &[i]);` tá correta?

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um loop para imprimir. Note que após o loop de leitura a variável i conterá o valor 5, que stá fora dos limites do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int i = 0;
    float nota[5];
    float total = 0, media = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Digite a nota do usuário!\\n");
        scanf("%f", &nota[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\\n", nota[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse linha onde você pega o valor digitado do teclado pelo usuário está faltando o nome do seu array das notas

```
scanf("%f", &[i]);
```

Correto:

```
scanf("%f", &nota[i]);
```

e na linha que você imprime as notas

```
printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\\n", nota[i]);
```

está falando um `For` para você percorrer os indices do array novamente para imprimir os mesmos.

segue o código: [code](https://onlinegdb.com/ryTcUqx34)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz somente duas alterações no seu código:
Troquei a linha que estava escrito `scanf("%f", &[i]);` para `scanf("%f", &nota[i]);` e 
implementei um laço `for` entorno da linha `printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\n", nota[i]);`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  int i = 0;
  float nota[5];
  float total = 0, media = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      printf("Digite a nota do usuário!\n");
      //Primeira alteração de &[i] para &nota[i]
      scanf("%f", &nota[i]);

  }

  //Segunda alteração um laço for para imprimir as notas coletadas
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\n", nota[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BeigeFickleAttributes)

Comment: Rodei no Code::Blocks e funcionou!                                                                    
Valeu Pessoal!!!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo o erro cometido foi algo bem simples, o seu "scanf("%f", &[i]);" está errado a declaração da variável, o correto seria "scanf("%f", &nota[i]);" pois desta você esta sinalizando o vetor corretamente. 
Percebi tbm um erro na hora de mostrar as notas que é, você não fez com que rodasse o vetor corretamente para mostrar cada nota escrita, no caso substituiria seu "printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\n", nota[i]);" por um for e o printf dentro.

Desta forma no caso:

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      printf("As notas digitadas foram %.2f\n", nota[i]);
  }